# Match buy and sell data with columns ['units','totalUnits', 'price'] whose rows are not equal and in uneven increments. Weighted Unit Price Problem

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Hello this is my first time posting a question.

In the most simple terms, I have a set of buy orders and sell orders and I am trying to determine the corresponding sell price for each buy order based on units and total units. I am using python but created an example in Excel because I thought it was easier to explain. I am trying to solve for the green highlighted column "Sell Price". I achieved a roughly accurate answer by using pd.merge_asof(buy,sell,on='TotalUnits', direction = 'nearest') and then backfilling the matches. But this solution does not consider any leftover units between buy and sells.
[Example of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUx5d.png)

Buy Data

| Units | Total Units | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.03 | 0.03 | 100 |
| 0.45 | 0.48 | 99.4 |
| 0.2 | 0.68 | 98.7 |
| 1 | 1.68 | 97 |
| 0.005 | 1.685 | 96.99 |
| 0.9 | 2.585 | 95 |

Sell Data

| Units | Total Units | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.98 | 0.98 | 110 |
| 0.5 | 1.48 | 109.6 |
| 0.15 | 1.63 | 109.2 |
| 1 | 2.63 | 108 |
| 0.4 | 3.03 | 107.856 |
| 0.9 | 3.93 | 106 |

Trying to Solve for Sell Price Column

| Units | Total Units | Price | Sell Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.03 | 0.03 | 100 | 110 |
| 0.45 | 0.48 | 99.4 | 110 |
| 0.2 | 0.68 | 98.7 | 110 |
| 1 | 1.68 | 97 | 109.58 |
| 0.005 | 1.685 | 96.99 | (repeat above) |
| 0.9 | 2.585 | 95 | (repeat above) |

Example calc for row 4 – Sell Price of 109.58

| Units | Total Units | Price | Weighted Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.3 | 0.3 | 110 | 33 |
| 0.5 | 0.8 | 109.6 | 54.8 |
| 0.15 | 0.95 | 109.2 | 16.38 |
| 0.05 | 1 | 108 | 5.4 |
| 1 | 1 |  | 109.58 |

I have two datasets. The first contains buy orders with columns ['Units','Total Units','Price','Sell Price']. The second contains sell orders with columns ['Units','Total Units','Price']. The Sell Price column in the buy data is empty.

I am trying to determine for each row in the buy data, based on the value of Units and Total Units, the corresponding price from the sell data. Determining the price is dependent on the order of rows and Total Units.

One way to summarize it is that each row in the buy data represents an action and they take place one after another. So for row 1 of the buy data, I will check the unit value of 0.03 against the sell data row 1 unit value of 0.98.

- If the buy unit is smaller than the sell unit then the full buy unit can be fulfilled.The correct sell price for the first row of buy data is 110. After the first buy  row has been satisfied there are 0.95 units (0.98 - 0.03) of the first sell row remaining. These "leftover" units will then be applied to the next row and so on.
- If the buy unit is greater than the sell unit then the sell price will be calculated taking a weighted average of (unit and price) from the sell data until the sell units fullfill the buy units. In row 4, buy unit = 1, this is exactly what happened.

I know this is probably confusing so I apologize. I am having trouble explaining the problem and have spent hours looking for a solution on the internet.

Comment: Please put your tables as text in the question.

Comment: Okay thanks I am trying now

Comment: Are these buy and sell orders similar to what one might imagine e.g. on an exchange market? If so, wouldn't you want to start buying at the lowest price, instead of start buying at the highest price?

Comment: Yes, the buy and sell data are exchange order book snapshots. The first row (the highest price) has to be purchased before the rows below it can be purchased.

Comment: Thank you for including the tables; would you re-format so that they are easily (individually) `copy-paste`-able?

Comment: Is your dataset small enough to consider a `for` loop? Or does it need to be fast/able to vectorise operations?

Comment: I have a buy and sell data set for every 30 minutes over the past couple of weeks. So around 1.5 million rows. What I am hoping to do is match sell price to buy price for each row of each 30 minute period dataset and then calculate the spread between each row.

Comment: I imagine that it would be best to make a price equation for the sell book. Where I can determine a price for each unit interval including unit values that fall between the units in my dataset. I just do not know how to do it.

Comment: To make sure I understand: your `buy` frame represents other traders' *sell* orders? That is, the price *you* can buy at? and your `sell` frame represents other traders' *buy* orders? The price that *you* can sell at?

Comment: Yes, that is right! For the sake of simplicity, you can also assume I already own all of the buy data orders at their equivalent units and price and now trying to figure out what they would sell for.

Comment: I feel like I'm misunderstanding something; what restriction causes you to need to start with the highest buy price and the highest sell price? Wouldn't you want to start with the *lowest* buy price and the highest sell price?

Comment: (assuming you're trying to calculate arbitrage opportunity?)

Comment: Yes sir! So for each 30 minute time period I will see the spread moving down the order book. It is not really what would happen real time but for my purposes, I need to.

Comment: When I made the example in excel I ordered the price incorrectly. But it should not matter what the price is as long as the logic moves from the top of the order book down. .

Answer (score 1):

**Update**
I have found a solution that is not perfect but close to accurate. I would still love to hear better solutions! I "solved" using the numpy.interp() function. I feed the function arrays of totalUnits and price from the buyData and each totalUnits value from sellData. The result matched the buy price to the sell price instead of the other way around.

```
buyData.columns = ['price', 'unit', 'totalUnits']
sellData.columns = ['price', 'unit', 'totalUnits']

xp = np.asarray(buyData['totalUnits'].copy())
fp = np.asarray(buyData['price'].copy())

rr,cc = sellData.shape
sellData['buyPrice'] = 0

for r in np.arange(rr):
    price = sellData['totalUnits'].iloc[r].copy()
    xx = np.interp(price, xp,fp)
    sellData['buyPrice'].loc[r] = xx.copy()
```

Here is the result. The red points represent the calculated buyPrice and the green points are the actual data points for price and totalUnits from the buyData.

[image: plot of results]